# ng-repeat : custom filter to show all rows of the same user if one validate condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat that loops over a list of proposed actions by a user. There can be one to many action per user. If one of these proposed actions validates a condition (a location), then all proposed action of this users should be displayed.

Said more abstractly, how to display all rows having a certain property, when one of these row has another property that validates a condition ?

I know I can provide a custom function as filter for the ng-repeat but so far all approaches I came up with implied to loop over the whole list for each item tested. Maybe I can rely instead on some more performant builtin feature of angular, hence this question.

Comment: @FooBar I did not requested "code", and I dont think the question requires any. I am not sure you understood the question right. I need to act on rows also based on the result of testing other rows.

Comment: Im afraid I cant help you with other approach, I would be looping over the list for each one the same. I´ll do what i can to help...+1 top

Comment: thanks, I found a way, I'll post an answer asap.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing expensive computation in the filter function for ng-repeat, I choose to to intercept and enrich the data upfront. This can be done in the controller once the promise is resolved, or better as an interceptor in the service.

In my specific case I added a new field "allLocations" to each items. Once this is done the filter function can test each row normally, i.e by testing it own attributes, without to have to loop over all items.

Even though there isn't many people who will ever read this, that is how I solved it.